# Axes labels piled up in exported pdf

Tags: plotting, labeling, save, regionplot

I am running this code, and it displays the picture I wanted. After that, I click on it and rotate it to look just so, then right-click and save it into a PDF.

But in the saved pdf, the axes labels $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are all piled up, not where they should be.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

```
A1 = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
A2 = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
A3 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
M = x1 A1 + x2 A2 + x3 A3 + B ;

bd = 1.2;
ell = RegionPlot3D[
   PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[M], {x1, -bd, bd}, {x2, -bd, 
    bd}, {x3, -bd, bd}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, Opacity[0.8, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True];

Show[ell]
```

Comment: Use `ViewPoint` or `ViewAngle` as an option in `RegionPlot3D` environment and set the orientation before exporting it or **Right click** and then use save graphics as.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- Instead of using AxesLabel, you can use the Labeled function to place the labels. This can sometimes give you more control over the label placement.
- Instead of right-clicking and saving, use Mathematica's Export function to save the plot.
- Increase Image Resolution.

  ```
  ell = RegionPlot3D[
  PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[M], {x1, -bd, bd}, {x2, -bd, 
  bd}, {x3, -bd, bd}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Opacity[0.8, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True];

  labeledEll = Labeled[Show[ell], {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, {Left, Bottom,    Back}];

  Export["plot.pdf", labeledEll, ImageResolution -> 300];
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I ran this code, but I do not see where plot.pdf went. I do not see it in the directory where I ran the code. Then I removed the ; after the labeledEll instruction just to see what happens, and it generated a very tiny picture.

Comment: and then I saved that tiny picture by right clicking and it did get saved, but in he saved picture there is no axes.